# How to refresh GridView after Insert

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, dataset, sqldataadapter

I'm fairly new to Vb, and my task is to create programmaly those whole process, creating SqlDataAdapter, DataTable, DataSet. However I still can't manage the right things to do and in what order. I can retrieve, Update, Delete and sometimes my Insert works but I can't get the fresh data from my DataBase straight after the insert. Also, I want to mention I have a GUID as UniqueIndentifier in my SQL Table which need to be populated with the rest of the data in the GridView. Thank you

I have tried to put SELECTCOMMANDE and call the method FILL after the Insert, also to clear the the DataSet, put the `gridControl.Datasource = Nothing`, lastly I tried to Update my SqlDataAdapter. None of those methods worked for me....:(

```vb
 gridView.AddNewRow()

 gridView.UpdateCurrentRow()
'sqlDa.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(str_select_command, connection)

            'sqlDa.Fill(dataS, "Representants")
            connection.Close()
            'gridControl.RefreshDataSource()
            'dataS.Clear()

            'dataS.Tables.Remove("Representant")


            'sqlDa.Update(dataS.Tables(0))
            ''sqlDa.Fill(dataS, "Representants")
            'gridControl.DataSource = Nothing
            'gridControl.DataSource = dataS.Tables(0)
            'gridView.PopulateColumns()
            'gridView.RefreshData()



        Try
                connection.Open()

            Dim Command = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TEST (prenom, nom, id_cie_12) " & "VALUES (@prenom, @nom, @id_cie_12)", connection)


            Command.Parameters.Add("@prenom", SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "prenom")
            Command.Parameters.Add("@nom", SqlDbType.NChar, 20, "nom")
            Command.Parameters.Add("@id_cie_12", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "id_cie_12")

            sqlDa.InsertCommand = Command

            gridView.RefreshData()
            bbiButton.Enabled = False


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally


         connection.Close()

        End Try
```

I'm expecting the data updated from the DataBase shown in the GridView.

Comment: What type of application is this? WinForms? asp.net? WPF?

Comment: Are you using the Microsoft DataGridView or a third party control? The DataGridView does not have a .UpdateCurrentRow method.

Comment: I dont know how to check it is an existing projet.. Could you help me get that info thank you

Comment: In the Solution Explorer double click on My Project. In the resulting window click Application on the left. There will be a label Application Type. The drop down box below this label will show the type of application.

Comment: To find out if what kind of grid you are using... In the design window, select the grid. Then in the Properties window, look at the very top. You will see System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView if it is the Microsoft grid. If not let us know what grid it is.

Comment: what I dont understand is everytime the user add a row how do I get the new data? Do I need to unbound dataset from sqlDataAdapter every Insert? create new DataTable? thank you

Comment: To get answers, you will have to answer my questions. I told you how to get the information.

Comment: You never give your parameters a value. You never execute your command. Most of your code is commented out. You set one property of what I presume to be a DataAdapter and then you do nothing with it.

Comment: You need to provide MCVE Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Of what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Public Class Form1
        Sub filterrecords(ByVal sender As String)
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
            Dim da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            Dim imgc As New DataGridViewImageColumn
            imgc = DataGridView1.Columns(5)
            imgc.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
        End Sub

       then Paste in Form Load 


    filterrecords("")

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      cn.Close()
and paste Here 


    filterrecords("")
```

Comment: what is the difference gridview.datasource gridcontrol.datasource